# Execute same query two different databases using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I execute the same query using two different databases within the same server using stored procedure all based on a variable(parameter)?

This has to be done in a stored procedure because of the way I'm using it. The information are stored in the same table names on both databases. I need the results to be dynamic based on a variable. If X variable is entered it needs to read from databaseA but if Y is entered it needs to read from databaseB.

All I have right now is a working query that will work is the dbo is changed each time. I've spent a lot of time searching for an answer, but I am unable to find anything. Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: This belongs on dba.se.

Comment: When you say `variable` do you mean a parameter sent to the sp?

Comment: Polish Prince there is no need for your unintelligent comments here

Comment: @rpcob Insulting other users, especially those trying to help, won't get you anywhere. Please stop doing this. Leaving closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use parameter and check in where clause and decide which database table to select data from Try this

```
--assuming both tables have same table structure
select * from database1.dbo.table where 'x' = @param1
union all
select * from database2.dbo.table where 'y' = @param1
```

or

```
if (@param1 = 'x') 
begin
  select * from database1.dbo.table 
end
else if (@param1 = 'y')
begin
  select * from database2.dbo.table
end
```

Comment: If I use the IF statement I get The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Comment: can you post your complete sql script in your question above? Also make sure user has access to both DB and tables.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfect. What I was missing was the Else If. I was leaving it Else and for some reason wouldnt execute.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT
  col FROM [Database' 
    + CASE @param WHEN 'X' THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END + '].dbo.table
    WHERE ...';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you are concatenating, say:

```
+ ' WHERE somecol <= dateadd(DAY, 1, ' + @DATE + '))';
```

Then yes, you will get an error (but not the one you point out). It's difficult to tell where in your pastebin code you are getting an error, since it doesn't have any dynamic SQL. But instead of the above pattern you should be using a strongly-typed parameter, e.g.

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2013-03-11'; -- no m/d/y ugliness please

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT
  col FROM [Database' 
    + CASE @param WHEN 'X' THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END + '].dbo.table
    WHERE somecol <= dateadd(DAY, 1, @date_param))';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@date_param DATE', @date;
```

I changed the variable name so you would see how it is passed in.

**EDIT** for the new pastebin you're trying to sort out, you need to change:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@date_param DATE', @DATE;
```

To:

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
  @SQL, -- unparameterized command
  N'@USERID VARCHAR(100), @OURORDERDATE DATE', -- param list
  @USERID,       -- param 1
  @OURORDERDATE; -- param 2
```

Unraveling more yarn and pulling more teeth, maybe you are after this, assuming that users X and Y are in database1 and the others are in database2:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'USE Database' 
  + CASE WHEN @UserID IN ('X','Y') THEN '1' ELSE '2' END
  + ';';

SELECT ...all the join stuff from your pastebin...
WHERE  (TABEL2.SOLDTOCUSTID = @USERID)
    and TABEL2.OURORDERDATE >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    and (TABEL2.OURORDERDATE <= dateadd(day, 1, @OURORDERDATE));';

EXEC sp_executesql 
  @SQL, -- unparameterized command
  N'@USERID VARCHAR(100), @OURORDERDATE DATE', -- param list
  @USERID,       -- param 1
  @OURORDERDATE; -- param 2
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I go about modify the middle part. This is were I am the most confused. Where you have "col FROM" would mine look like "Select (tables) From [Database2' + @USERID + ' When..."

Comment: @rpcob can you stop putting your code in pastebin after pastebin and put the part you're stuck on in the question? It's really hard to understand where you're going wrong at this point and I don't know what on earth you mean by `[Database2' + @USERID...` - do you have a different database for each user?

Comment: There are two databases which is split between many users.

Comment: @rpcob ok, so can you share any secrets about how the code is supposed to know whether a user is in database 1 or database 2?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is **4 part naming convention** and **dynamic construct your query statement**. And also, if your databases are not located on the same server, you will need **linked server** or use **OpenRowset.**

Assumption: your databases are located on the same server, then in your store procedure, you will need a parameter to accept database name @dbname.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from '+ @dbname + '.dbo.tablename'
exec(@sql)
```

If your databases are located in different server, then first creat linked server, then use linked server, or directly use openrowset. And in your store procedure, you will need both @serverName and @DBName

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from ' + @ServerName + '.' + @DBName + '.dbo.tablename'
exec(@sql)
```

Note: Here, the @servername is the linked server name when you created it.